# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined, even though focus is being called

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make an AI for a computer that plays tic-tac-toe out of javascript, but I'm running into a console error that says that it can't read the property focus of undefined.
My code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Determine whether you are going first
  const humanTurnFirst = Math.random() >= 0.5;
  /**
   * Get an array of the text content of each of the tic-tac-toe buttons
   * @returns {Array} Array of the text content of each square, from top-left to bottom-right.
  */

  const getLayout = () => {
    // Array of buttons ordered from top-left to bottom right
    const buttons = [
      document.getElementsByClassName('corner-top-left')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('edge-top')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('corner-top-right')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('edge-left')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('center-button')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('edge-right')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('corner-bottom-left')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('edge-bottom')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('corner-bottom-right')[0],
    ];
    const layout = [];
    buttons.forEach(button => layout.push(button.innerText));
    return layout;
  };
  /**
   * Make the computer play a square
   * @param {Node} button The square to play
   */

  const autoClick = (button) => {
    console.log('button', button);
    const $turn = document.getElementsByClassName('turn')[0];
    $turn.innerText = 'Not your turn yet...';
    const $allButtons = [...document.getElementsByClassName('button')];
    const $allDisableableButtons = $allButtons
      .filter(
        element => element !== button
        && !element.disabled,
      );
    $allDisableableButtons.forEach((disableableButton) => {
      const thisButton = disableableButton;
      thisButton.disabled = true;
    });
    console.log('button', button);
    button.focus();
    setTimeout(() => {
      button.click();
      $allDisableableButtons.forEach((disableableButton) => {
        const thisButton = disableableButton;
        thisButton.disabled = false;
        $turn.innerText = 'Try clicking an empty space.';
      });
    }, 500);
  };
  /**
   * Calculate the best square for the computer to play.
   * @param {Array.<Node>} layout Array of the text of each square, from top-left to bottom right.
   * @param {Node|Boolean} previous The last move that you've made.
   */
  const computerTurn = (layout, previous, localHumanTurnFirst) => {
    const buttons = [
      document.getElementsByClassName('corner-top-left')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('edge-top')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('corner-top-right')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('edge-left')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('center-button')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('edge-right')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('corner-bottom-left')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('edge-bottom')[0],
      document.getElementsByClassName('corner-bottom-right')[0],
    ];
    const $corners = [...document.getElementsByClassName('corner')];
    // If there is no previous move, the computer goes first with a random corner.
    if (!previous) {
      const randomBelow4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
      const randomCorner = $corners[randomBelow4];
      autoClick(randomCorner);
      /* If the computer is going first,
        has already filled out a random corner,
        and there is nothing in the center,
        it will place another X in one of the adgacent corners.
      */
    } else if (
      !localHumanTurnFirst
      && layout.filter(element => element === 'X').length === 1
      && previous !== buttons[4]
    ) {
      const filledOutCorner = buttons.filter(element => element.innerText === 'X')[0];
      const diagonalCorner = document.getElementsByClassName(filledOutCorner.className
        .split(/\s+/)[2]
        .replace(/(left|right)/, match => (match === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left'))
        .replace(/(top|bottom)/, match => (match === 'top' ? 'bottom' : 'top')))[0];
      const emptyCorners = $corners.filter(corner => corner.innerText === 'Empty');
      const adjacentCorners = emptyCorners.filter(element => element !== diagonalCorner);
      const potentialCorners = adjacentCorners
        .filter(
          corner => document.getElementsByClassName(`edge-${corner.className.split(/\s+/)[2].split('-')[1]}`)[0].innerText === 'Empty'
            && document.getElementsByClassName(`edge-${corner.className.split(/\s+/)[2].split('-')[2]}`)[0].innerText === 'Empty',
        );
      const randomPotentialCorner = potentialCorners[
        Math.floor(
          Math.random()
          * potentialCorners.length,
        )
      ];
      autoClick(randomPotentialCorner);
    } else if (
      !localHumanTurnFirst
      && buttons.filter(button => button.innerText === 'X' && button.className.split(/\s+/).includes('corner')).length === 2
      && buttons.filter(button => button.innerText === 'O' && [...document.getElementsByClassName(`corner-${button.className.replace('button edge edge-', '')}`)].every(element => element.innerText === 'X')).length === 1
    ) {
      autoClick(buttons[4]);
    }
  };
  /**
   * Add event listener for squares
   * @param {Boolean} localHumanTurnFirst Whether you go first.
   */
  const squaresOnClick = (localHumanTurnFirst, isHumanTurn) => {
    const humanLetter = localHumanTurnFirst ? 'X' : 'O';
    const computerLetter = localHumanTurnFirst ? 'O' : 'X';
    const $squares = [...document.getElementsByClassName('button')];
    $squares.forEach((square) => {
      const thisSquare = square;
      square.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (isHumanTurn) {
          thisSquare.innerText = humanLetter;
          computerTurn(getLayout(), thisSquare, localHumanTurnFirst);
          squaresOnClick(localHumanTurnFirst, false);
        } else {
          thisSquare.innerText = computerLetter;
          squaresOnClick(localHumanTurnFirst, true);
        }
        thisSquare.disabled = true;
      });
    });
  };
  /**
   * Turn the welcome screen into the game screen.
   * @param {Boolean} localHumanTurnFirst Whether you go first.
   */
  const spawnSquares = (localHumanTurnFirst) => {
    const $turn = document.getElementsByClassName('turn')[0];
    const $mainGame = document.getElementsByClassName('main-game')[0];
    $turn.innerText = 'Try clicking an empty space.';
    $mainGame.className = 'main-game dp-4 tic-tac-toe';
    $mainGame.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Tic-tac-toe grid');
    $mainGame.innerHTML = `
      <button class="button corner corner-top-left corner-top corner-left">Empty</button>
      <button class="button edge edge-top">Empty</button>
      <button class="button corner corner-top-right corner-top corner-right">Empty</button>
      <button class="button edge edge-left">Empty</button>
      <button class="button center-button">Empty</button>
      <button class="button edge edge-right">Empty</button>
      <button class="button corner corner-bottom-left corner-bottom corner-left">Empty</button>
      <button class="button edge edge-bottom">Empty</button>
      <button class="button corner corner-bottom-right corner-bottom corner-right">Empty</button>
    `;
    squaresOnClick(localHumanTurnFirst, localHumanTurnFirst);
    if (!localHumanTurnFirst) {
      computerTurn(getLayout(), false, localHumanTurnFirst);
    }
  };
  /**
   * Create the button that starts the game.
   */
  const welcomeButton = (localHumanTurnFirst) => {
    const $welcomeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('start-button')[0];
    $welcomeButton.addEventListener('click', () => spawnSquares(localHumanTurnFirst));
  };
  /**
   * Turn the main game into the welcome screen.
   * @param {Boolean} localHumanTurnFirst Whether you go first.
   */
  const welcome = (localHumanTurnFirst) => {
    const $mainGame = document.getElementsByClassName('main-game')[0];
    const $turn = document.getElementsByClassName('turn')[0];
    $turn.innerText = 'Welcome!';
    $mainGame.className = 'main-game dp-4 welcome center';
    $mainGame.innerHTML = `
    <section class="welcome-section">
      <h2 class="welcome-heading">Welcome to unbeatable tic-tac-toe!</h2>
      <p class="welcome-text">
        According to random chance, your turn has already been chosen
        as ${localHumanTurnFirst ? 'first (with an X)' : 'second (with an O)'}, which 
        means that the computer is going 
        ${localHumanTurnFirst ? 'second (with an O)' : 'first (with an X)'}. <strong>
          Press the start button to start the game!</strong
        >
      </p>
    </section>
    <button class="start-button button">Start</button>
  `;
    welcomeButton(localHumanTurnFirst);
  };
  welcome(humanTurnFirst);
});
```

When I call computerTurn when the first elseif condition is true, I get this weird output in the console:
[image]

The problem is in these lines, I think:

```
    } else if (
  !localHumanTurnFirst
  && layout.filter(element => element === 'X').length === 1
  && previous !== buttons[4]
) {
  const filledOutCorner = buttons.filter(element => element.innerText === 'X')[0];
  const diagonalCorner = document.getElementsByClassName(filledOutCorner.className
    .split(/\s+/)[2]
    .replace(/(left|right)/, match => (match === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left'))
    .replace(/(top|bottom)/, match => (match === 'top' ? 'bottom' : 'top')))[0];
  const emptyCorners = $corners.filter(corner => corner.innerText === 'Empty');
  const adjacentCorners = emptyCorners.filter(element => element !== diagonalCorner);
  const potentialCorners = adjacentCorners
    .filter(
      corner => document.getElementsByClassName(`edge-${corner.className.split(/\s+/)[2].split('-')[1]}`)[0].innerText === 'Empty'
        && document.getElementsByClassName(`edge-${corner.className.split(/\s+/)[2].split('-')[2]}`)[0].innerText === 'Empty',
    );
  const randomPotentialCorner = potentialCorners[
    Math.floor(
      Math.random()
      * potentialCorners.length,
    )
  ];
  autoClick(randomPotentialCorner);
} else if (
  !localHumanTurnFirst
  && buttons.filter(button => button.innerText === 'X' && button.className.split(/\s+/).includes('corner')).length === 2
  && buttons.filter(button => button.innerText === 'O' && [...document.getElementsByClassName(`corner-${button.className.replace('button edge edge-', '')}`)].every(element => element.innerText === 'X')).length === 1
) {
  autoClick(buttons[4]);
}
```

It appears like autoClick is being called thrice. This doesn't appear to be affecting my actual code, but I think console errors are pretty annoying, and I want to get to the bottom of this.
Thanks so much for your time, and I'm sorry if I'm being really vague.

EDIT: console.log('button', button)

Comment: can you check the line 43, are you calling the actual class name. Check for any typo

Comment: basically the error is something you are trying to access in the dom but which is undefined, just check by putting a console.log() of the element, and not able to identify where are you calling the focus , can you post the line where you are getting error

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I put a console.log(button) in the autoClick function in various places.

Comment: what it is giving undefined or what console.log("button", button). Even if its undefined you will be able to understand easily

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I don't understand. Do you want me to put "button" before the button so that people don't get confused?

Comment: yes, so if its undefined you will be able to identify easily. Since in chrome if you dont put string before or after it will be empty you wont be able to understand whether it is showing anything or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out why this is.

I need to make my `autoClick` function return immediately if the `button` is [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (or `undefined`) with this magical one liner:

```js
 if (!button) { return; }
```